# Walk subdirectories in Python starting from the subdirectories

Tags: python

I've the following dir structure:

```
root
└── env
    ├── team_1
    │   ├── policies
    │   │   └── file.yaml
    │   └── roles
    └── team_2
        ├── policies
        └── roles
```

and I need to read **all the files under a team directory and merge them to create one unique file**.

This is my attempt:

```
env_path = os.path.join('root', env)

if os.path.exists(env_path):
     for team_dir in os.listdir(env_path):
         for root, dirs, files in os.walk(team_dir):
            print(root, dirs, files)
```

The problem is that `os.walk` doesn't return anything when I pass `team_dir`. I should use `os.path.join(env_path, team_dir)` but at that point it returns the entire tree which I don't want. How can youreturn from `os.walk` the subdirs of already a subdir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you *have* to use `os.path.join(env_path, team_dir)` or `os.walk` won't find anything.

But if you don't want all the hierarchy, just remove the start of the string:

```
 for team_dir in os.listdir(env_path):
     for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(env_path, team_dir)):
        for f in files+dirs:
            print(os.path.join(root,f)[len(env_path)+1:])  # strip start of path + separator
```